# What stops an intelligent foe from just grabbing your Animated Shield?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, shield

An [animated shield](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#animated) floats in front of you to protect you as if you were holding it.
However, it has no physical connection to you like a real shield does.

I understand its usage against mindless creatures,
but what is there to prevent an intelligent creature from actually taking the shield and locking it away?
It would provoke an AoO, but otherwise… why wouldn't an intelligent creature do it?

Comment: Note: There is the *Pin Shield* feat (Complete Warrior, p. 103) which allows a two weapons fighting combatant to give up its off-hand attacks in exchange for negating the Shield Bonus to AC of its opponent for the round. There is also Targeted [Dispel](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm) on the Shield, 1d20 + min(Caster Level, 10) against the item caster's level, and if it succeeds the magical properties (thus Animated) are suppressed for 1d4 rounds.

Answer (score 5):

> What stops an intelligent foe from just grabbing your Animated Shield?

**Nothing**, see [Disarm](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#disarm). It remains your shield, the fact that you are holding it by magic rather than muscle doesn't change that.

> ... what is there to prevent an intelligent creature from actually taking the shield and locking it away?

The Attack of Opportunity, the opposed roll and that if they want to actually hold it rather than knocking it to the floor they have to make an unarmed attack. Oh, and the opportunity cost of trying this instead of casting *Power Word - Kill*, say.

> ... why wouldn't an intelligent creature do it?

See above.

Comment: Huh.  It's sort of funny to me that it's apparently easier to disarm a shield than a weapon: "If the targeted item isn’t a melee weapon, the defender takes a -4 penalty on the roll."

Comment: @DuckTapeAl That's nothing. As written, disarming someone of something other than a weapon causes them to drop *their weapon* to the ground: "If you attempted the disarm action unarmed, you now have the weapon. If you were armed, the defender’s weapon is on the ground in the defender’s square."

Comment: @DuckTapeAl: True, given that a shield is generally *strapped* and not held, it should quite obviously be harder to disarm a shield.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I don't know that I'd say "generally." Roman scutas (the classic tower shield) are held by a handle behind the center boss. Bucklers, Viking shields, target shields, and many other similar round shields also have a central handle and no strap. That's a pretty broad swath of shielddom. GMJoe's point stands, though. I'd never noticed that, and would have houseruled it if I had.

Comment: @BlueFootedBooby: Interesting, a quick search on Google Images show some scutas with just a handle and some with additional straps and this matches my memory of RPG events, but then their historical accuracy is of course dubious :)

Comment: IIRC, those straps were generally used during transit, rather than battle.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Someone twisting a shield that is strapped to an arm, would be akin to twisting their arm. Check [this](https://youtu.be/SjYHONBYWck?t=6m8s) out.

Comment: @Ruut: Ah! Never thought of that. Indeed the shield could easily turn into a dead weight then, and worst of all the aggressor is hidden behind the shield the whole time making it very difficult to push him back.